# How to make Duotone Effect by GraghicsMagick?

Tags: effect, graphicsmagick

In ImageMagick, I can do "**Duotone**" effect by following command,

**convert rose_grey.jpg   -fill blue -tint 100  rose_blue.jpg**

But in GraphicsMagick, it doesn't work.

I am stuck: How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm! In ImageMagick you could do it with `-clut`, but GM doesn't have that. Or you could do it with `+level-colors` but GM doesn't have that. Or you could do it with `-fx` but GM doesn't have that. Mmmm! How about using ImageMagick?

Comment: You can also make a HALD-CLUT in ImageMagick using `convert hald:3 -colorspace gray -fill blue -tint 100 hald.png` and then apply it to the rose with `convert rose_grey.jpg hald.png -hald-clut result.png` and then think you are going to get GraphicsMagick to use that CLUT with its `-hald-clut` method - but that doesn't work either :-(

Comment: I do not use or have Graphicsmagick installed. Basically all the API's lack the functionality of Imagemagick. You might get a similar effect by converting you image to black and white and then compositing a plain colour image over it with blend if it available.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Many thanks for looking into it. Duotone is just a normal effect, but it hard to do in GraphicMagick. Thinking to convert to ImageMagicK

Comment: This is a fake duotone.